# Do I need Xbox Live Gold to play with my friends on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-one, xbox-network

My friend plays Minecraft on a PS4 and he has PS-plus. I recently got an Xbox.

Can he join my world or I join his, without an Xbox Live Gold account?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play online with your friend, **you will need to have Xbox live**. Most, if not all, online Xbox games need you to buy Xbox live to access the online features. The same goes for Minecraft. You *can* actually play on local play, but your friend needs to be near you (around 5-15 feet away). You will also need to have a Microsoft account.

Comment: It may be noteworthy that Minecraft is not part of the list of FTP games that does no longer require a subscription, unlike some of its competitors like Roblox.

Comment: Minecraft is not free to play though, unlike Roblox.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you ever needed XBox Live Gold to do this with Minecraft.  This required that you are both using the Bedrock edition, and that crossplay be available.

Here is a guide of how someone with a Playstation 4 can join other games.

https://www.windowscentral.com/minecraft-guide-how-set-xbox-live-cross-play-playstation-4

As a bonus, Microsoft has made a lot of multiplayer games which used to require XBox Live Gold free to play as of April 21, 2021.

https://support.xbox.com/en-NZ/help/subscriptions-billing/manage-subscriptions/multiplayer-unlock-free-to-play-games